# PDF.js no longer able to save / view .pdf in Firefox v 33.0.2

Tags: firefox, adobe-reader, magento

I noticed when upgrading from FireFox version 32.0.3 → 33.0.2 that I can no longer print or view <kbd>.pdf</kbd> files.

When navigating `Menu` → `Options` → `Applications` & filtering by `Portable Document Format (PDF)` - regardless of which action I choose an error occurs.

**When choosing the `Save File` or `Use Adobe Reader` actions:**

The download staggers and upon retrying completes yet the file is corrupt & contains .html code instead.

**When choosing the `Preview in Firefox` action: I get the following error in Firebug:**

> An error occurred while loading the PDF.
>
> PDF.js v1.0.473 (build: 1694cd8)
>
> Message: undefined

I've found the following resource which may be related to this:

[How to fix broken "Print to AdobePDF" ?](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1316203?start=0&tstart=0)

I discovered this using Magento, here is my initial post:

[PDF files printed via Magento damaged / failing to download?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/42070/pdf-files-printed-via-magento-damaged-failing-to-download?noredirect=1#comment57577_42070)

I realized this isn't Magento specific once I saw it working perfectly in Google Chrome / Opera & IE. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a link to an example (broken?) PDF that you can share?

Comment: We have the exact same problem and are waiting for a response from Mozilla Support. https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1028486 I'll post here if there are any updates on it.

Comment: @DavidPostill - unfortunately no, can't provide a public URL.

Comment: @JaapHaagmans - thanks for the heads up, appreciate it. It's really driving me a little nuts. I've temporarily moved over to Google Chrome but missing Firebug (vs Dev tools)

Comment: @moose Same here. Which version of Magento are you running? I seem not to have this problem on Magento 1.9.0.1.

Comment: @JaapHaagmans - that's interesting. I'm experiencing the problem on 1.7.0.2.

Comment: If you're able to do a shadow-upgrade on a test-environment, we could confirm that upgrading has the desired effect. The underlying error could possibly come from a problem with TCPDF.